# camel cookbook examples builds fail

Tags: maven, apache-camel

When I try to build the examples from camel cookbook examples I get the following error:
The POM for org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:jar:2.20.0-SNAPSHOT is missing,
Has anyone else tried building these examples?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like maven central does not contain the snapshot version of the artifact, but the [main version](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.camel%7Ccamel-maven-plugin%7C2.20.0%7Cmaven-plugin). Just remove the string `-SNAPSHOT` in your pom and use version `2.20.0`.